# Adding unallocated space without data loss

Tags: server, partitioning, 22.04, disk-management

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04. I have zabbix server installed on it. Unfortunately, disk space is running out. this server is a virtual machine on VMware ESXi. I added 25 GB to the server but unfortunately I don't know how to add 25 GB to the existing partition so as not to lose data. Is it possible at all?

[image: fdisk -l /dev/sda]

[image: sudo sfdisk --list-free /dev/sda]

Comment: First make sure you have a backup. Second you have a backup? Next you resize the partition (`man parted`) afterwards you can resize the filesystem, for ext4 you can use `resize2fs`.

Comment: Yes i have backup. Its possible to extend /dev/mapper-ubuntu-vg-ubuntu-lv?

`Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              594M  1.4M  593M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   12G  9.4G  1.6G  86% /
tmpfs                              2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          1.5G  253M  1.2G  19% /boot
tmpfs                              594M  4.0K  594M   1% /run/user/1000`

Comment: Add additions to the question, not the comment. This is not readable.